# my __init__.py file finds the flask module in the editor but not in the console

Tags: python

i'm following a tutorial on flask and im trying to import some of the classes or functions from: flask, flask_sqlalchemy and flask_login.

and on the editor they are recognized and they dont show up as a problem, but when i try to run the files they give me these errors

on `app.py` :

```
    from websiteScripts import create_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

it gives the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\myuser\website\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from websiteScripts import create_app
  File "c:\Users\myuser\website\websiteScripts\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
```

and on `__init__.py`:

```
    from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import Login

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "thepain"

    return app
```

it gives the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\myuser\website\websiteScripts\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

please help me fix, ive already tried: refreshing my venv and reinstalling flask and the rest.

Comment: It all looks like a typical misconfigured virtual environment or something like that

Comment: explain please, im dumb so i dont know what to do

Comment: Well, firstly, I'm not sure, secondly, I explain poorly, but I'll try, roughly speaking, you could, for example, install the flask in the system python, and run the code from under the virtual environment, or you could install the flask in the virtual environment and run without it .

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you either do not have a virtual environment or you have not activated it before trying to launch your flask program.

**1. Create a virtual environment**

`$ python3 -m venv venv`

This will create a directory called `venv` into which you can install your python dependencies

**2. Activate your virtual environment**

On linux/max use:
`$ sourve path-to-dir/venv/bin/activate`

On windows use:
`$ path-to-dir\Scrips\Activate.ps1`

You'll know that you're working in the virtual environment if you see `(venv)` before your shell prompt

**3. Install your dependencies**

Install flask and other dependencies with `pip install flask other-module-name`

**4. Launch your app**

First export your environment variables

Mac/linux: `$ export FLASK_APP=main.py` (or whatever your main python module is named)

Windows: `$ $ENV:FLASK_APP='main.py'`

Use the same command to set `FLASK_ENV` to `development`

Finally, execute `$ flask run` to start your app.

Refer to [the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/installation/?highlight=virtual%20env#virtual-environments) for more information about setting up your flask application.

Comment: it appears my venv doesnt want to activate, my life is pure hell

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Note that the syntax for the windows commands must be run in powershell, Command Prompt commands differ slightly

Comment: well, it does give me an error and it is:

c:\Users\myuser\website\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 : Impossibile caricare il file C:\Users\myuser\website\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1.
Execution script is disabled in the system in use. For ulterior informazion, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
In riga:1 macchina:1
+ c:\Utenti\andre\sito web\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : Errore di protezione: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: UnauthorizedAccess